# In Angular 7 select dropdown value id passes to all select dropdowns in ngFor list

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using ngFor gets label and select dropdown list in particular div tag in angular 7. But if i select option from any one select dropdown its changes happens in all select dropdown list in div tag

```html
<div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor='let item of Bedroom.PBeda'>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <span class="font-wt-600">{{item.PBedName}}</span><br /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <select class="form-control" name="value" id="bedID{{item.PBedID}}"[(ngModel)]="beds.value (ngModelChange)="onChangeBedsDetails($event,item.PBedID)">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you make stackblitz example for this or share your `onChangeBedsDetails` methods code so we can better understand what you doing in that method.

Comment: pass type of bet to `onchangeBedsDetails` method and set value based on bed type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why all the drop down values are changing is because you have the same `ngModel` for all the dropdowns, instead store the values in an array as below:

**Component HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor='let item of Bedroom.PBeda'>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <span class="font-wt-600">{{item.PBedName}}</span><br /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <select class="form-control" name="value" id="bedID{{item.PBedID}}" 
                    [(ngModel)]="beds.value[item.PBedID]" (ngModelChange)="onChangeBedsDetails($event,item.PBedID)">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

**Component TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  beds: any = {
    value: []
  }
  Bedroom: any = {
    PBeda: [
      {
        PBedID: 1,
        PBedName: 'hello'
      },
      {
        PBedID: 2,
        PBedName: 'hello2'
      }
    ]
  }

  onChangeBedsDetails(event, id) {
    console.log(this.beds.value[id]);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wv5aft)